# Get friend interests using android facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

In my app my intention is to get some interests of a friend like music, books, tv. This information is public. For this I think I don't need to send a permission.
Based on facebook (poor)documentation, mainly this links:
[Field Expansion](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/field_expansion/) to get friend interest I only need to pass friend ID in the expanded friends field.
Doing some tests on GraphExplorer I see it creates the following query to get movies form some friend:

```
MY_ID?fields=friends.uid(FRIEND_ID).fields(movies)
```

I use this and execute execute this code on a Request.newMyFriendRequest asynchronously:

```
Session activeSession = Session.getActiveSession();
    if(activeSession.getState().isOpened()){
        Request request = Request.newMyFriendsRequest(activeSession, 
            new GraphUserListCallback(){
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(List<GraphUser> users, Response response){
                    GraphUser user = users.get(0);
                    JSONObject friendLikes = user.getInnerJSONObject();
                    try {
                        JSONArray data = friendLikes.getJSONObject("friends").getJSONArray("data");
                        Log.i("JSON", friendLikes.toString());
                        addInterests(data, 0);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        });
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("fields", "friends.uid("+friendID+").fields(movies)");
        request.setParameters(bundle);
        request.executeAsync();
```

All times I execute this code I receive the following error from JSON:
W/System.err(694): org.json.JSONException: No value for friends.
If this isn't the way to get friend interests using GraphAPI, what do I need to do to get these values?

Answer (score 1):

**[EDIT]** Solved posting friends_likes permission on Login. Permission is not sended inside Request.
I modified a bit my solution. If anyone is interested:

```
String fqlQuery = "SELECT music, books, movies FROM user where uid ="+friendID;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("q", fqlQuery);
        Request request = new Request(activeSession, "/fql", bundle, HttpMethod.GET, 
            new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.i("INFO", response.toString());
                }
            });
        Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
```

Comment: I just want to get user interests from sdk. How can I get this, can u help me @learner.